# Remove already committed git branches

Tags: git, workflow, git-svn

My normal pattern is to branch from master, do a ton of work, then rebase and `git svn dcommit`. How can I clean up all my old branches?

Basically I want to find any branches that have `git-svn-id:` in the message and `git branch -D` those.

NOTE: `git branch --no-color --no-track --merged` gets me most of the way, but if I ever get into a situation where I need a `git fetch -f` (because of a crazy git-svn bug) I would have to go and rebase all the branches myself.

Comment: Shouldn't all the branches have git-svn-id: in the commit message? or are you referring to the latest commit?

Comment: Yeah, the HEAD will only have a `git-svn-id` if it have been merged

Comment: alright, then I suppose it is a matter of using some batch file to list local branches and check them for that condition. I will probably do the deletion separately since it is rather risky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sort-of-one-liner:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads |
while read branch; do
    if git show -s $branch | grep 'git-svn-id:'; then
        git branch -D $branch
    fi
done
```

Note that this is untested; I don't use git-svn, and it's just based on the requirements in the second paragraph of your question. You might try it first with an echo in there instead of `git branch -D`, to make sure the list of branches looks like what you'd expect. I can help refine it as necessary.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Can you format it for inclusion in a .gitconfig so I can do `git gcbr` and it will clean up my branches?

Comment: @PaulTarjan: Really with anything nontrivial, it's better to put it in a script called `git-gcbr` somewhere in your path, so that it's actually possible to read and edit later. That also makes it easier to do things like adding a dry-run/force option in case you want to tread cautiously. (Or you could just have it echo the branch names, inspect, and pipe to `xargs git branch -D`, I suppose.)